# How to take an element from the next level of nesting

Tags: html, css

I have this structure generated by WordPress plugin:

```html
<span>
  <input/>
</span>
<label></label>
```

I need to write my css like this:

```css
input:focus+label {
  color: #1743fc;
  transform: translateY(1rem) translateX(0.5rem);
}
```

But the "+" and "~" rules don't work. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) now in some browsers:

```
span:has(input:focus) + label {
  color: #1743fc;
  transform: translateY(1rem) translateX(0.5rem);
}
```